# This YouTube video is purporting that the Stack Overflow survey endorsed their service

Tags: discussion, advertising, statistics, survey, legal

I started to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6e6U50FIcQ where a YouTube content creator (developer by profession) "analyses" the Stack Overflow Survey Data.

About [3:24 minutes](https://youtu.be/t6e6U50FIcQ?t=202) in he shows this little gem - right between other legit survey results:

[image: A fake survey question asking for favorite online learning platform with result being Skillshare at 100%.]

Could not remember that question - looked for it.

I am livid - it is NOT OK to use SO's survey in this regard - someone of SO might want to get this video down.

---

I am aware that [advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising) is for adverts on this site - I tagged it none the less so the SO advertising team gets to look at this.

---

Did a *Contact us* to SO as well, after getting the suggestion in SOCVR.

Comment: The vid has ~15k views - on 90k followers this guy makes money with his channel.

Comment: According to YouTube's [product placement guidelines](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/154235?hl=en), this sort of thing has to be disclosed, to Youtube, at the very least. The page doesn't provide any recourse for watchers, but reporting the video is likely enough to get Google to take a hard look at it without disclosure.

Comment: I am fine with YT creators promoting things - what makes me barf is that he _designed and insinuated it_ right into the survey so it "looks as if" it was a legit result. Anybody with 3.5 brain cells knows thats it is a plug - call me lawful good.

Comment: @fbueckert It is best if someone SO official does the Youtube/Goole poking, however. If Patrick did a "contact us" then the right people have been notified.

Comment: Yeah, I getcha.  It's sketchy as all get out; same as those *endless* marketing pages that extoll, "guides" and, "strategies" to buy their material.  If you're less lawful good, though, a DMCA takedown will get rid of it; there's no option to counterfile as fair use in Youtube.  That itself is a problem, so I can't really endorse that as a valid option.

Comment: Let me leave this comment before Hans does: "Nice, now their video got even more views"

Comment: @rene Would be a plot twist if that was me .... (**it is not**) .... taking that vid down is probably leading to less views then letting it stay on in the long run...

Comment: *"Anybody with 3.5 brain cells knows thats it is a plug."* Exactly. So why are you livid about this? Besides, even though it may be unethical, I don't think it's illegal.

Comment: It is trying to promote skillshare and it is obviously fake.  
It cannot be 100% percent.  
Also, there is no section called `Favorite Online Learning Platform For Creators`.  
And any of the titles of the survey topics are not italic, but the title in this one is italic. It is 99% percent developer tools html editing.

Comment: This feels like such small fry, it is barely worth getting mildly ticked off, nevermind "livid". The screenshot does not mention Stack Overflow - how is it being endorsed?

Comment: I am not a fan of what I perceive to be YouTube's overly legalistic approach to deciding who can see what based on vague interpretations of US law - especially for us folks outside of US borders - and I don't know that I want to fuel that, either. The material screenshotted here is obviously an advert, and sensible readers will exercise due caution.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate, that helps. I'm at work, so haven't watched it. Is it meant tongue-in-cheek, perhaps?

Comment: _"The first 500 of **my** subscribers..."_ should make it abundantly clear to any reader that this is not StackOverflow speaking. Without this last point I would be inclined to agree that it has a chance at deceiving (at least from the screenshot). But with it there (and the other going-ons in the video) I find it hard to see deceit here. Yes, it could be even clearer, but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: YouTube hosts all sorts of dubious, downright terrible, honestly just the worst of society content. They also host beautiful, amazingly insightful and helpful content. User beware.

Answer (score 37):

I don't think this was intended to mislead viewers. It is clearly a parody question for an advertisement.

The background music volume increases significantly during the advertisement, which is how many YouTube channels and podcasts indicate ads. The section starts with the host making a few sarcastic remarks about how the format of this "question" doesn't match the rest of the survey or even have any other options, lampshading the joke. If he were actually trying to trick viewers, he could have easily made it look convincing instead. He ends the advertisement by saying that the segment was "courtesy of Skillshare", and the video description also says that it is "sponsored by Skillshare".

> [image]

Comment: If we hop up and down and claim to be really annoyed-livid-angry-barking, does that help any? `:-p`

Comment: There is music in the background before the faked "result" - There is nothing of "Whats that doing here" that I could make out. There is music in the video afterwards as well. The fake result is styled to fit to the screenshots taken from the actual survey. There is _absolutely_ intend to deceive - he even talks about "them putting infos about skillshare below the result - although everybody knows skillshare"  - after showing that for some time the video goes full-body-capture and the real advertisement begins ... He ends HIS full body capture with sponsore comment.

Comment: I don't know which video you watched Jeremy, but there was certainly no "What's that doing here?!" in the one I watched.

Comment: He **never** sais the faked survey result page is **not** part of the survey.

Comment: Ok I finally watched it ^^ The author of the video inserted its promotional content in a funny way in order not to disrupt the flow of his video. Still, this is _obviously_ an ad. But, yeah OK ... Pow's law... I see absolutely no harm though, and I stand with you Jeremy.

Comment: To the people who downvoted: did you downvote based on the criteria `This answer is not useful` or because you disagree with some presupposition you are inferring?

Comment: @Felipe not sure how long you've been on meta, but that's how meta works.

Comment: The words that come out of their mouth literally skip from results from the survey to "favorite online platform" saying that skillshare has 100%. Of course that's intended as some kind of "that survey said that people prefer skillshare at 100%". They are enumerating survey questions then smoothly skip to their "survey question".

Comment: OK, I just watched some of the video to hear that "significant volume increase" you mentioned, and I'm pretty sure there's no such thing. I mean, the background music does have louder and quieter sections (although even the louder parts are so quiet compared to the guy's voice that I had to put on headphones and turn up the volume to really hear them), and the fake question does coincide with one of the louder ones. But the music gets just as loud e.g. around 7:00 in the video (in the social media question, when he talks about YouTube — or maybe that's a _really_ well hidden ad for YouTube?).

Comment: Also, what the guy actually says at the end of the ad segment is "*...because the first 500 of y'all who sign up using that link at the top of the description get two months of Skillshare Premium for free, and that is courtesy of Skillshare, so, Skillshare, thank you!*" Which isn't really the same thing as saying that the *segment* is "courtesy of Skillshare", even if it does imply the existence of some kind of a promotional deal.

Answer (score 12):

No longer livid. I have no problem whatsoever, with

- content creators to need / use sponsorship to get an income
- inlined sponsor endorsement in videos
- someone "from the field" commenting on the survey

I have a problem with doing the above by styling part of the endorsement in a way that suggests this is connected to SO's userbase, connected to *me* or part of the SO survey at all.

From the comments and reactions I can concur that to a certain degree this seems to be a ***me problem***. Ethics, morals and legal aspects differ over countries and some people seem to view this way of advertising as smart and smooth.

Is it as bad as "Microsoft Tech Scams" or Telemarketers?

- No.

Is it ok to do it like that?

- For me: Heck no

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) / the comments and answers showed me again, that opinions differ. I see it as [*fraud*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fraud):

> Wrongful or criminal deception intended to result in financial or personal gain.

and

> A person or thing intended to deceive others, typically by unjustifiably claiming or being credited with accomplishments or qualities.

---

What I take from it? Let SO the company handle it - next time it's just gonna be a *Contact me* message.

Comment: I think this is mostly a cultural thing. In one particular country in the western world, people are so brainwashed by sneaky adverts that they don't even react to them any longer. Characters in movies driving one particular car, having one particular watch or drinking one particular drink (zoom in on the product for x seconds). People anywhere else in the world find such things repulsive, while the natives of that one country thinks it's all good. They even regard commercials as valid forms of entertainment, like the big annual show where they show commercials mixed with a tiny bit of sports.

Comment: However Google is showing this ad in countries where deceptive advertising is against the law, so it's still useful to flag the video so they can restrict it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's perfectly fine to place an Ad like this.

And you're completly right with your assumption:

> Anybody with 3.5 brain cells knows thats it is a plug

Just browsing through some comments shows that many realized it's an ad.

[image]

Youtube creators have to be creative, they have to standout from the rest. Implementing an advertisment in such a way, shows at least that the creator used some of their 3.5 (probably more) braincells.

For my part. I think this kind of Ad placement is much better and a lot smoother for the viewer, than just cutting the video in half, reading down 10 pages of ad-statements and then continuing normally.

Answer (score -4):

I'm posting this as an answer despite feeling like there wasn't much of a question to begin with:

I don't agree with his practice, but I also don't think 'livid' is an appropriate response to this. Let's consider the offense in question:

- Promoting a third-party service in a dubious way, that might make a layman infer that it was a part of the SO survey.

Was this an honest thing to do? Well, maybe not, but that may also be a subjective opinion. The real questions here should be:

- Does this action violate YouTube TOS? If so, it is in YouTube's hands.
- Does this action violate StackOverflow TOS? If so, it should be reported as an offense, but seeing as this is done on another platform (YouTube), I don't think it could be considered a violation.

The bottom line is, people have the right to lie. They also have the right to be deceitful. If this is deemed unethical or dishonest but does not violate any TOS, he will most likely see a backlash from his audience.

In my opinion, since you feel more strongly about it than I do, you would be best commenting on the video to show his audience that he is deliberately being misleading.

Comment: "The bottom line is, people have the right to lie. They also have the right to be deceitful." Eh, this is a wishy washy subject. In some cases or jurisdictions, lying is punishable by death. In others, it's encouraged. In this case, there are Terms of Service, licensing, etc. legal requirements that prohibit such lying, so no, people do not have the right to lie in this context.

Comment: That's fair, and I can't speak for all jurisdictions but I mean the internet specifically. What I mean is that it needs to be outlined somewhere as a potentially liable offense. When we swear under oath to tell the truth, and then lie, only then are we responsible. But if a guy on the street says he caught the abominable snowman and it turns out to be a lie used to attract people to his restaurant, we don't usually send that person to jail.

Comment: One does not have to be under sworn oath to be required to not lie. There are also laws against things like slander/libel, false advertising, etc.

Comment: This sort of smurf is why we have GOOP and Nutritional Supplements that only supplement the producer's wallet.

Comment: @user4581301 Now you're just taking it to the extreme and decontextualizing things. This becomes a different debate: Is a manipulative company responsible for a foolish consumer who gives in to wishful thinking? It's a much bigger discussion than "This guy on youtube put an ad for skillshare in his video and now I'm livid"

Comment: @Felipe I don't think it's reasonable to expect all watchers to apply critical thinking; we have annual retraining sessions for our techs that reinforce that, because many don't.  Our techs are not programmers, but repair aircraft parts, so that thinking is pretty critical.  You or I wouldn't fall for it, but there's lots of people that will.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree, it would be unreasonable to expect the average individual to not be taken in by misconduct or dishonest practice. That's certainly not my view, In fact, I'm not even defending the guy. Although if you see some of the comments to the answer above mine, it appears that it was a pretty obvious plug, intended to be so.

Comment: Also, very interesting to see the votes coming in for what appears to be a passionate topic for some people? As far as I can tell, the only thing worth noting in this question is the degree to which this could be harmful to S.O., which, in my opinion, is naught, as I've explained. I am making no moral arguments.